# Can't Convert Geometry to WKT: ORA-13199 to_wktgeometry CLOB write failed

Tags: oracle, geometry, oracle12c, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to read a large table containing polygon geometries from Oracle using Spark. The spark app reads it using multiple connections to the Oracle database. I'm encountering this wkt geometry error while running the queries like that below on Oracle 12.2

```
SELECT
    id
    ,SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(geometry) as wkt
FROM
    parcels PARTITION (PRT_A)  -- {{paritition}}
WHERE
    -- Include only polygons contained in the bounding box below
    sdo_relate(
        geometry,
        SDO_geometry(2003,8307,NULL,
            SDO_elem_info_array(1,1003,3),
            SDO_ordinate_array(-87, 34, -86, 34)  -- {{coords}}
        ),
        'mask=inside querytype=window'
    ) = 'TRUE'
    -- AND
    -- SDO_UTIL.VALIDATE_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(geometry)) = 'TRUE'
```

**ORA-13199: to_wktgeometry CLOB write failed**

Unfortunately, running a separate query to check if/which of these geometries are invalid takes a very long time. I haven't gotten it to finish even on a small partition.

This `parcels` table has **151 million rows**, with partitions (I think by geography), a spatial index on `geometry`, and a couple other indexes on `id` and separately `PBD_LOC_LONG_MIN`, `long_max`, `lat_min`, `lat_max`.

Relevant columns and types:

```
| Column           | Type         |
|------------------|--------------|
| ID               | NUMBER(38,0) |
| GEOMETRY         | SDO_GEOMETRY |
| PBD_LOC_LONG_MIN | NUMBER(9,6)  |
| PBD_LOC_LONG_MAX | NUMBER(9,6)  |
| PBD_LOC_LAT_MIN  | NUMBER(8,6)  |
| PBD_LOC_LAT_MAX  | NUMBER(8,6)  |
| PROP_ST          | VARCHAR2(2)  | <-- partitions are subsets of these
```

My approach has been to iterate this over the tables 14 partitions and batches of coordinates representing bounding boxes. A single small bounding box succeeds, but even in that case, I cannot include the filter for valid geometries. Requesting multiple queries over several bounding boxes in sequence, and unioning the result never succeeds, eventually times out.

EDIT: the goal of this was to "skip" bad geometries causing the ORA-13199 error by running these filtered queries in parallel. Unfortunately `SDO_UTIL.VALIDATE_WKTGEOMETRY` takes too long to compute.

Any advice for how to handle this ORA-13199: to_wktgeometry CLOB write failed error?

EDIT:

With the help of [Albert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65257254/5289570), I managed to partially resolve the issue preventing creation of WKT using this query:

```
-- This after select helped with performance /*+ parallel(p,8) */
select
  p.ID
  ,SDO_UTIL.to_wktgeometry_varchar(p.geometry)
from 
  parcels PARTITION (APB_NJ) p
where 
  p.prop_st = 'NJ'
  AND SDO_UTIL.GETNUMVERTICES(p.geometry) < 157
```

However this vertices limit could only be determined by trial and error, and throws out some ~14k records. Without this additional filter, I get "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small." Not ideal.

Comment: That is very odd. I have never seen that sort of failure. SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY() does return a CLOB but the actual implementation varies with the versions. What exact Oracle version do you run ? Is it 12.2 ? Or 12.1 ?

Comment: Something else - unrelated to the issue: why do you use `mask=covers` ? It is unlikely to return what I imagine you expect, i.e. getting all the geometries in that query window. Actually it is very likely to not return anything. If you want to get the shapes in that window, use either `SDO_ANYINTERACT` or `SDO_INSIDE`. Or even `SDO_FILTER`. But even then those three will return different results.

Comment: And finally if your goal is to return all the shapes in a query window from a partitioned table, then you just run the query against that table. There is no need to run it specifically against each partition. Is the spatial index partitioned too ? Or is is a single `GLOBAL` index ? And what is the partitioning criteria ? I also forgot this: there is variant of `to_wktgeometry()` that actually returns a `VARCHAR2` string. That may be possible if the parcel have "simple" shapes, i.e. with not too many vertices so that the WKT string is less than 32767 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @AlbertGodfrind. I have Oracle database 12c enterprise release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit. PL/SQL release 12.2.0.1.0.

Comment: I chose `SDO_RELATE` after reading that it implicitly runs a fast primary filter before running the more precise secondary filter. But perhaps this is true for all SDO_* functions. I'll update the query. In fact I want to pull potentially all geometries eventually, and some would be missed by failing to be completely covered or inside a bounding box.

Comment: The spatial index is not partitioned. The actual partitions are based on groups of states defined in a `prop_st` state field type varchar(2). Each of 14 such partitions have 5-15 million records. I was advised by DBA's to try hitting one partition at a time to reduce the impact of this intensive IO. Indeed most of the parcel shapes are simple, I think. But some are likely complex with many vertices and/or large collections with multiple element types. I was hoping to "skip" these by running multiple bounding box filtered queries in parallel.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of `COVER`. Oh but I see you changed your example to use `INSIDE`. That is much better. `COVER` was decidedly wrong. Let me switch to a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, I never encountered this kind of error. But before investigating that specifically, there are two important points I want to make:

**1. The spatial predicate you use:**

```
    sdo_relate(
        SDO_geometry(2003,8307,NULL,
            SDO_elem_info_array(1,1003,3),
            SDO_ordinate_array(-87, 34, -86, 34)  -- {{coords}}
        ),
        'mask=cover querytype=window'
    ) = 'TRUE'
```

That will not give you the right answer: `COVER` is the wrong predicate.  However, I see that you edited your question to change it to `INSIDE`. That is much better and it is important to understand the difference also with `ANYINTERACT`.

The classification of spatial predicates is based on the 9-intersection model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) that defines how two geometric shapes interact based on how their interior, boundary and exterior interact, hence 9 possible interactions, hence the term "9 intersections"

Oracle Spatial defines its predicates based on this classification. It essentially gives names to each kind of intersection. This is illustrated in the following illustration.

[image]

Notice in particular that INSIDE and COVEREDBY have very specific meanings, different from their usual meaning in daily life:

- INSIDE means **strictly** inside: the boundary of the green shape **does not**
  touch the boundary of the red shape: green is *inside* red, or the reverse: red *contains* green.
- COVEREDBY means that the shape is also fully contained, but its boundary **touches** the boundary of the container: green is *covered by* red, or: red *covers* green.

Those are very different relationships, and having two different names makes it possible to distinguish one case from the other. To test for both you would combine them in the `SDO_RELATE` predicate : `mask=inside+coveredby`

It is also important to understand the difference between `INSIDE` and `CONTAINS`. In your case, you are searching for the land parcels that are **inside** your query window. You would use the reverse if you wanted to find something like: "in which county is that parcel" (assuming you did not known that from attributes). Then you would reverse the order of the shapes in the spatial predicate, like this:

- find parcels in a county:
  `SDO_RELATE (parcel_geom, county_geom, 'mask=inside+coveredby')`
- in which county is this parcel ?
  `` SDO_RELATE (county_geom, parcel_geom, 'mask=contains+covers`) ``

Using the combination of `inside+coveredby` is important in this particular example. Using `inside` only would miss all those parcels that are on the boundary of the county!

You can also see now that `covers` in your original query was totally wrong, and `coveredby` would have been equally wrong. `inside` is much better.

There is however something else worth considering: the difference between `INSIDE` and `ANYINTERACT`. They are illustrated here:

[image]

This shows US counties and a red area used to select them - one a user could draw on a screen. Not too different from your query window approach.

On the left is a result of the INSIDE query. On the right is ANYINTERACT. The difference is obvious. On the left we return those shapes that are strictly inside our query window. This will be the same for your rectangular query window: obviously, it will go over some parcels, and those will not be returned. In other words, as you move your query window, you will **miss** quite a few parcels.

On the right you get all those parcels that cross the edge of your query window. But as you move it, you get them **again** since they interact with both windows. So you need to eliminate those parcels from the result set. Hopefully you have a discriminant primary key to eliminate them.

All those spatial operators perform in two stages: a *primary* filter that uses the spatial index to quickly isolate the candidates, then a *secondary* filter to do the actual spatial calculations. One possibility I would consider in your case, since you always query using rectangular windows is to use the `SDO_FILTER()` operator instead. It only applies the *primary* filter, and does not do any spatial computations, so is much faster. It will however also return **more** matches than you expect, and the same land parcels will be returned by queries using adjacent query windows - but that also happens with `SDO_ANYINTERACT` anyway.

This shows what happens with SDO_FILTER vs SDO_ANYINTERACT:
[image]
Notice **all** shapes (US counties) intersect the red query window, just like for SDO_ANYINTERACT ... Well, almost: notice the one at the top right corner. It is clearly outside the red query window. ANYINTERACT would not return it. But FILTER does because it only compares the MBRs of the shapes. And the MBR of that shape actually does intersect the query window. So the result is approximate: you get more results than you want, but then the adjacent query window will return it anyway and you need to remove those duplicate matches anyway ...

One more point: instead of using `SDO_RELATE(...,'mask=inside')` you can just say `SDO_INSIDE(...)` for a simpler syntax. Same for `SDO_ANYINTERACT()`, `SDO_CONTAINS()` etc.

**2. Querying individual partitions:**

You say that you are doing so to reduce the impact of I/Os hitting all partitions at the same time. But you also indicate that the data is spatially partitioned, i.e. that each partition covers a specific area. That would mean that your query window would hit one partition at a time only anyway. But: that depends on the size and area covered by each query window. And you need to be certain that a given query window only ever matches one specific partition. Otherwise, you need to repeat that query for the other partitions, since your query window may spatially overlap partitions. At worst, assuming you have 20 query windows, you need to repeat those for each partition, so run each 14 times ?

Also, since the spatial index is not partitioned, you will essentially isolate all matching shapes (via the primary filter, i.e. the index) then throw the pointers away to only retain those pointing to the current partition. IMO, it would be more efficient to just run all those queries against the entire table instead of the individual partitions.

You may want to clarify the partitioning criteria used for the table, and possibly also create the spatial index as partitioned. The spatial indexing mechanism will automatically only consider the partitions that are relevant to your query window for each query.

**3. The CLOB error.**

This is very odd, and I have no idea where it comes from. Before 12.2, the WKT generation was made in Java. Since 12.2 it is native code (for better performance), and the function does return a CLOB, and for that it does create a temporary LOB. It could be that some memory leak causes the error ... Or that the temporary lobs are not properly cleaned out in this version ...

One possible solution could be to get the WKT in a VARCHAR2 instead, using `to_wktgeometry_varchar()` instead of `to_wktgeometry()`. But that is only possible if the WKT can fit in less than 32k. That may be the case if you deal with land parcels, that have typically simple shapes (with few vertices)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I better understand spatial predicates in Oracle now. I initially went for a too-restrictive containment because I was unsure how to remove duplicates afterward, but this approach makes sense. I can filter duplicated `ID`'s afterward.

Comment: Regarding the CLOB error, thanks for suggesting the varchar version. It completes much faster on this table, revealing this error: "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small". Do you know how I can catch these and return only the ID's instead? If I filter on [SDO_UTIL.GETNUMVERTICES](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_util-getnumvertices.htm#SPATL1236), roughly how many would approach 32k bytes?

Comment: What do you do with the results ? Do you write them to a table, like an `INSERT ... SELECT` ? Or do you use a cursor ? Maybe the simplest is wrap the call to `SDO_UTIL.to_wktgeometry()` in a user-defined function, catch the exception and log some context into a log table (the id of the row you got the geometry from, and also the geometry). That will help identify what rows cause the error (and you can continue the processing with the others).

Comment: You could actually do something clever, like convert to WKT varchar. If that fails with ORA-06502, then retry to CLOB, and if that fails, log the error and context, and continue.

Comment: I use a cursor and interface with python through cx_Oracle. Unfortunately I'm unable to create user defined functions due to lack of privileges on my company database. I'm working around this by trying a range of vertices limits, fetching results, and logging when a limit is too high. Ultimately I want to write these results to files in chunks, but it's hard to verify the min #vertices that causes this error. Each query is still pretty slow.